# Как получить список приложений на устройстве пользователя, в которых можно построить маршрут?

Tags: swift, карты, ios11

Каким образом можно проверить стоит ли на девайсе пользователя определенное приложение (яндекс.карты, гугл.карты или нативные карты), для того, чтобы составить список приложений, в которых можно построить маршрут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно через deeplink, например [googlemaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme?hl=ru) или [yandexmaps](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/About-docpage/), таким же образом можно проверить и доступность приложений

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {

    // открываем googlemaps
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
} else if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"yandexmaps://")!)) {
    // открываем yandexmaps
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=37.62,55.75&z=12")!)
} else {
    // откриваем нативное приложение или проверяем дальше
}
```

---

upd

- еще нужно будет добавить ключи в `info.plist` для параметра `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` типа `Array` ссылки

[image: пример ключей]

- для нативных карт есть такая же проверка `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "maps://")!)`, но в последних обновлениях есть проблемы (она всегда возвращает `true`), можете прочитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603120/how-to-check-if-apple-maps-is-installed)

Comment: спасибо за ответ) нативные карты тоже можно удалить с девайса. нужно как-то проверить, что они там есть