# Как построить маршрут в яндекс картах через openURL?

Tags: swift, yandex-maps-api, ios11

Как построить маршрут между двумя точками в яндекс картах, открыв их через openURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать таким образом:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"yandexmaps://")!) {
    let urlString = "yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?rtext=\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude),\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)~51.532147,46.612396&rtt=mt"
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlString)!)
}
```

Подробнее см. тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-ios-app-docpage/

Также нужно не забыть добавить ключ `yandexmaps` в `info.plist` для параметра `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` (подробнее про ключ можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/922962)).