# Как построить маршрут в google картах, открыв их через openURL?

Tags: swift, google-maps-api, ios11

Как построить маршрут между двумя точками в google картах, открыв их в родном приложении через openURL?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как построить маршрут в яндекс картах через openURL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923084/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-openurl)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так это можно сделать:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!) {
    let urlString = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=51.532147,46.612396&directionsmode=driving"
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlString)!)
}
```

Также нужно не забыть добавить ключ `comgooglemaps` в `info.plist` для параметра `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` (подробнее про ключ можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/922962)).